# How to determine the location of the signature in Itext PDF Java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, sign, pki

I'm doing a program that Digitally sign PDF document using Itext Library .

The problem is the location of the signature when i set it to visible signature

how can i determine the location of the signature ?

here's how to create the Rectangle of signature:

```
new Rectangle(float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury);
```

and when i play with this i found it's Related to the size of the signature rather than the location  of it . ?

any help ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: If there's a signature field in your file, that field has a property called `/Rect`, but you don't need to know that property, because you can use the *name* of the signature field to add the visible signature. If you don't have a signature field, your question is unclear. How would a software program know where you want to put the signature? A software program can't read your mind ;-)

Comment: No , my question in simple words how can i determined where to put the signature "in the code" . - I don't have a signature filed.

Comment: I mean how to tell the program to put the signature in the top,left, right ... etc of the page ?

Comment: Your page has its coordinate system determined by its crop box (defaulting to its media box). Thus, you have to choose the rectangle coordinates relative to the crop box coordinates.

Answer (score 10):

According to your comments to your original question, you want to know

> how to tell the program to put the signature in the top,left, right ... etc of the page.

I assume you use a routine like this:

```
public void sign(String src, String dest, 
    Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider, 
    CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location) 
    throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException { 
    // Creating the reader and the stamper 
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src); 
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest); 
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0'); 
    // Creating the appearance 
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance(); 
    appearance.setReason(reason); 
    appearance.setLocation(location); 
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig"); 
    // Creating the signature 
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest(); 
    ExternalSignature signature = 
    new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider); 
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, 
    null, null, null, 0, subfilter); 
}
```

> *(Code sample 2.1 from the White Paper [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf) by Bruno Lowagie (iText Software))*

and want to adjust the `Rectangle` in the line

```
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
```

to meet your requirements.

The coordinates in this rectangle are given relative to the coordinate system of the page you sign. You can retrieve the data defining this coordinate system using the `PdfReader` method `getCropBox(int index)` (`index`: the page number. The first page is 1).

```
    Rectangle cropBox = reader.getCropBox(1);
```

Furthermore you need to know the width and height for your signature. E.g.

```
    float width = 108;
    float height = 32;
```

With these data you can calculate a `Rectangle rectangle` e.g. like this:

```
    // Top left
    rectangle = new Rectangle(cropBox.getLeft(), cropBox.getTop(height),
                              cropBox.getLeft(width), cropBox.getTop());

    // Top right
    rectangle = new Rectangle(cropBox.getRight(width), cropBox.getTop(height),
                              cropBox.getRight(), cropBox.getTop());

    // Bottom left
    rectangle = new Rectangle(cropBox.getLeft(), cropBox.getBottom(),
                              cropBox.getLeft(width), cropBox.getBottom(height));

    // Bottom right
    rectangle = new Rectangle(cropBox.getRight(width), cropBox.getBottom(),
                              cropBox.getRight(), cropBox.getBottom(height));
```

and use it to define the visible signature position and size:

```
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(rectangle, 1, "sig");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .
I have tried your data but unfortunately all of them appear in Top Left.

Comment: Please supply the test document in question. I tested the `Rectangle` definitions here and they worked all right.

Comment: @Yassering Have you meanwhile got everything up and running? Or have you found a PDF to share which illustrates that *all of them appear in Top Left* behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not so clear, but i think that following code might work for you....

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String pdfFile = args[0];
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);

    AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();

    for(String signame : fields.getBlankSignatureNames()) {
      List<AcroFields.FieldPosition> positions = fields.getFieldPositions(signame);
      Rectangle rect = positions.get(0).position; // In points:
      float left   = rect.getLeft();
      float bTop   = rect.getTop();
      float width  = rect.getWidth();
      float height = rect.getHeight();

      int page = positions.get(0).page;
      Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(page);
      float pageHeight = pageSize.getTop();
      float top = pageHeight - bTop;

      System.out.print(signame + "::" + page + "::" + left + "::" + top + "::" + width + "::" + height + "\n");
    }
  }
```